# Enable Alt-tab in Windows running through Linux terminal

Tags: windows-server-2008, gtk, alt-tab, linux-terminal

Tearing my hair out over this.

On my desk at work is a HP HSTNC-001L-TC terminal, and through this I connect to our server which has Windows Server 2008.

The problem is alt-tab doesn't work. I've been told that because I'm on a Linux terminal then it doesn't pass the Alt-tab combination through to Windows properly, and that's why I cannot alt-tab through my applications.

So how do I get alt-tab to work properly within Windows Server 2008 which I connect to through this HP Linux terminal?

I think the terminal is running Gtk2

Comment: FYI there are alternatives see Table 8-3 Keyboard Shortcuts in a Remote Desktop Session - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are connected from linux to your windows server. If you have rdesktop (which rdesktop in a shell to see if you have it, or ask your administrator), alt-tab works correctly if your focus is on the remote session. If not, take a look at this page to see if that would help you:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/remote-desktop-tips-and-tricks.html

If that still does not help, you may have to do some keymapping yourself.